# Editing an attribute before it's mapped to an object in SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I'm storing file paths using sqlalchemy. At the moment these are stored as absolute paths, but I need them to be stored as relative. However I don't want to have to manually join the paths with the base directory every time they're needed, instead this should be done automatically before they are mapped to an object. This way anytime I query the database I'll get back an absolute path, even though they're stored relative. How would I do this? Mapper configuration?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One of possible solutions - add method into mapped class that will convert relative path into absolute path. This method would need to know root dir path - which can be defined by global scope variable.

```
global_base_path = "/home/user"

...

class Path(Base):
    ...
    relative_path = Column(String(2048))
    ...
    @property
    def absolute_path(self):
        return os.path.join(global_base_path,self.relative_path)


q = session.query(Path)
c = q.first()
print c.absolute_path
```

Comment: I'm having a problem getting this to work. Using a property as you suggested worked fine until I tried to use it in a query. AFAIK to do this I need to hybrid properties, right? But I'm having problems with getting that working. All I've done is replace @property with @hybrid_property and when I try to query I get this error `TypeError: Boolean value of this clause is not defined`

Comment: I may have some idea how to deal with this new problem. Please post your latest model and query code that your have problem with. You can create new question on [stackoverflow.com](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sqlalchemy) for doing so - or just use  [gist](https://gist.github.com/).

Comment: I've posted it as a new question. [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14504284/querying-a-hybrid-property-in-sqlalchemy](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14504284/querying-a-hybrid-property-in-sqlalchemy). Thanks for your help.

Comment: Looks like you got your answer before I was able to look into it :) That is the power of asking questions on stackoverflow. Good luck with your work.

Comment: Haha yeah I assumed it was you until I just looked at the username. Stackoverflow has helped me so much recently.  Thanks anyway.