# SQLAlchemy hybrid_property and expressions

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I am working on storing some data produced by an external process in a postgres database using sqlalchemy. The external data has several dates stored as strings that I would like to use as datetime objects for comparison and duration calculation and I'd like the conversion to happen in the data model to maintain consistency. I'm trying to use a hybrid_property but I am running into problems based on the different ways that SQLAlchemy uses the hybrid_property as an instance or class.

A (simplified) case looks like this...

```
class Contact(Base):
    id = Column(String(100), primary_key=True)
    status_date = Column(String(100))

    @hybrid_property
    def real_status_date(self):
        return convert_from_outside_date(self.status_date)
```

with the conversion function something like this (the function can return a date, False on conversion failure or None on being passed None)...

```
def convert_from_outside_date(in_str):
    out_date = None

    if in_str != None:
        try:
            out_date = datetime.datetime.strptime(in_str,"%Y-%m-%d")
        except ValueError:
            out_date = False
    return out_date
```

When I use an instance of Contact, contact.real_status_date properly works as a datetime. The problem is when Contact.real_status_date is used in a query filter.

```
db_session.query(Contact).filter(
    Contact.real_status_date > datetime.datetime.now())
```

Gets me a "TypeError: Boolean value of this clause is not defined" exception, with the

```
in_str != None
```

line of the conversion function as the last part of the stack trace.

Some answers (https://stackoverflow.com/a/14504695/416308) show the use of a setter function and the addition of new column in the data model. Other answers (https://stackoverflow.com/a/13642708/416308) show the addition of @property.expression function that returns something sqlalchemy can interpret into a sql expression.

Adding a setter to the Contact class works but the addition of new columns seems like it shouldn't be necessary and makes some table metadata parsing more difficult later and I'd like to avoid it if I can.

```
_real_status_date = Column(DateTime())

@hybrid_property
def real_status_date(self):
    return self._real_status_date

@real_status_date.setter
def value(self):
    self._real_status_date = convert_from_outside_date(self.status_date)
```

If I used an @.expression decorator would I have to implement a strptime function that is more sql compatible? What would that look like? Is there something wrong with the conversion function that is causing trouble here?

Comment: basically yes, if you are using @.expression, that means you are composing an expression that is evaluated entirely by the database (e.g. in aggregate).    However, the use case is not quite making sense to me - how do you intend to use this attribute at the expression level?  Because it can return either a date value or `False`, that means it doesn't have a fixed type.  I'm not sure how you can use such an expression in SQL cleanly as you should use expressions that are CAST into a single type.

Comment: The field is used in two ways - 1. to compare instance of Contact to other data where I have an actual datetime. Something like `if contact.real_status_date > datetime.datetime.now()` 2. In queries of the Contact table to filter out dates of specific `s.query(Contact).filter(Contact.real_status_date > last_week`. The hybrid property was intended to preserve the original string incarnation of the date to retain compatibility with the system that originated the data that originally entered the db.

Comment: OK so the SQL version here would be OK if it always returned a date or NULL, right?   Basically the main thing you have to work out is the string->date on the database side which depends on what kind of database you're using (different functions on postgres, mysql, oracle, etc.), all of them have functions to achieve this.

Comment: I see, thanks, will update with details when I have an answer - just using two separate columns for now and forgoing the hybrid_properties

Answer (score 0):

As [zzzeek](https://stackoverflow.com/users/34549/zzzeek) mentions, you could add the following to your class

Depending on your DB, it might already interpret a python `datetime` object

So it could work only modifying your conversion function to:

```
def convert_from_outside_date(in_str):
if in_str:
    try:
        return datetime.datetime.strptime(in_str,"%Y-%m-%d")
# Return None for a Null date
return None
```

Otherwise you need to add an expression function:

```
@real_status_date.expression
def real_status_date(self):
    return sqlalchemy.Date(self.real_status_date)
```